# Phonegap Android Geolocation example doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I try to use geolocation with android 4.0.4 and Phonegap 1.9. I tried the first example of http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

I added the lines in AndroidManifest.xml and plugins.xml. I enabled GPS and with google maps its working. But when I start the html file with Phonegap on my galaxy nexus it shows: "Finding geolocation..." and does nothing.

Thats the complete Logcat output:

```
07-17 10:13:08.296: D/CordovaWebView(7612): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-17 10:13:18.984: D/CordovaWebView(7612): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-17 10:13:19.132: D/OpenGLRenderer(7612): Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-17 10:13:19.179: D/OpenGLRenderer(7612): Flushing caches (mode 1)
07-17 10:13:33.984: I/CordovaLog(7800): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
07-17 10:13:33.984: I/CordovaLog(7800): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
07-17 10:13:33.984: D/CordovaLog(7800): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
07-17 10:13:33.984: D/DroidGap(7800): DroidGap.init()
07-17 10:13:33.991: D/CordovaWebView(7800): >>> loadUrl    
(file:///android_asset/www/geolocation.html)
07-17 10:13:33.991: D/PluginManager(7800): init()
07-17 10:13:33.991: D/CordovaWebView(7800): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-17 10:13:34.023: D/DroidGap(7800): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/geolocation.html)
07-17 10:13:34.023: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7800): Ignore this event
07-17 10:13:34.046: D/libEGL(7800): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
07-17 10:13:34.046: D/libEGL(7800): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
07-17 10:13:34.054: D/libEGL(7800): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
07-17 10:13:34.070: D/libEGL(7800): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
07-17 10:13:34.140: D/dalvikvm(7800): GC_CONCURRENT freed 139K, 2% free 12959K/13191K, paused 3ms+2ms
07-17 10:13:34.210: D/OpenGLRenderer(7800): Enabling debug mode 0
07-17 10:13:34.210: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7800): Ignore this event
07-17 10:13:34.390: D/Cordova(7800): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/geolocation.html)
07-17 10:13:34.390: D/CordovaWebView(7800): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-17 10:13:34.390: D/DroidGap(7800): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
07-17 10:13:34.390: D/DroidGap(7800): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/geolocation.html)
07-17 10:13:34.398: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(7800): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27701 of [8609a15dfa], db=/data/data/de.xxxx.ble.html5/databases/webview.db
07-17 10:13:34.398: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(7800): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = os_unix.c: open() at line 27701 - "" errno=2 path=/CachedGeoposition.db, db=/data/data/de.xxxx.ble.html5/databases/webview.db
07-17 10:13:34.413: D/DroidGap(7800): onMessage(networkconnection,3g)
07-17 10:13:36.398: D/DroidGap(7800): onMessage(spinner,stop)
```

It entered the onDeviceReady() Function but i thinks it doesn't call onSuccess nor onError.

Thats my code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>  
  <head>    
  <title>Device Properties Example</title>    
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    

  // Wait for Cordova to load    
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);    

 // Cordova is ready      
 function onDeviceReady() {  
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);    
 } 

// onSuccess Geolocation        
function onSuccess(position) {        
var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');  

element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude                 
          + '<br />' + 
                    'Longitude: '          + 
           position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +   
                    'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +   
                    'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +   
                    'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +   
                    'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +   
                    'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +  
                    'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp 
                    + '<br />'; 


   }    


    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object      
        function onError(error) {        
alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +              
      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');   
}    


   </script>  
   </head>  

   <body>    
<p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Update: I just discovered that my code is working with the Internet Explorer 9, but not firefox beta or chrome on android 4.0.4 on my Galaxy Nexus. It isn't working as an android package withe Phonegap and not as a normal html5 page. With an IPhone4S it's working!

If you have any ideas what's the problem, let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Update: Even a normal HTML5 with Geolocation isn't working on my Galaxy Nexus! I tried Firefox 14, Chrome 18 and the standard browser. But google maps is working! Can somebody help??

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Google Api SDK! For example the 2.3.3 / 10 Version.